# Difference between SKIP_SIBLINGS and SKIP_SUBTREE

Tags: java, file, io, nio

Is anybody aware of the difference between these two `FileVisitResult`? 
Directly from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) oracle tutorial:

> **SKIP_SUBTREE** – When preVisitDirectory returns this value, the
>   specified directory and its subdirectories are skipped. This branch is
>   "pruned out" of the tree.
>
> **SKIP_SIBLINGS** – When preVisitDirectory returns this value, the
>   specified directory is not visited, postVisitDirectory is not invoked,
>   and no further unvisited siblings are visited. If returned from the
>   postVisitDirectory method, no further siblings are visited.
>   Essentially, nothing further happens in the specified directory.

Comment: ........did you read your own question? It SAYS what the difference is.

Comment: Frankly, even the names tell you what the difference is.

Comment: Ehy Colleen, thanks for responding very kind. Though It's crystal clear to you. For me it's kind of confusing otherwise I would not have posted this question. Thanks for your interest though

Comment: how is it confusing? SKIP_SUBTREE skips subtrees and SKIP_SIBLINGS skips siblings. What?!

Comment: Just to make more clear, we can say that FileVisitResult.SKIP_SIBLINGS: This means that the traversal process will continue without visiting the siblings (files or folders) of that particular Path. FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE: This means that the traversal process will continue without visiting the rest of the tree entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you answered your own question but if the explanation on oracle's tutorial didn't clear all your doubts, this is what the [javadoc](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/FileVisitResult.html#SKIP_SIBLINGS) says:

**SKIP_SUBTREE**

> Continue without visiting the entries in this directory. This result is only meaningful when returned from the preVisitDirectory method; otherwise this result type is the same as returning CONTINUE.

**SKIP_SIBLINGS**

> Continue without visiting the siblings of this file or directory. If returned from the preVisitDirectory method then the entries in the directory are also skipped and the postVisitDirectory method is not invoked.

And here is the code for [FileVisitResult](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/nio/file/FileVisitResult.java#FileVisitResult):

```
public enum FileVisitResult {
/**
 * Continue. When returned from a {@link FileVisitor#preVisitDirectory
 * preVisitDirectory} method then the entries in the directory should also
 * be visited.
 */
CONTINUE,
/**
 * Terminate.
 */
TERMINATE,
/**
 * Continue without visiting the entries in this directory. This result
 * is only meaningful when returned from the {@link
 * FileVisitor#preVisitDirectory preVisitDirectory} method; otherwise
 * this result type is the same as returning {@link #CONTINUE}.
 */
SKIP_SUBTREE,
/**
 * Continue without visiting the <em>siblings</em> of this file or directory.
 * If returned from the {@link FileVisitor#preVisitDirectory
 * preVisitDirectory} method then the entries in the directory are also
 * skipped and the {@link FileVisitor#postVisitDirectory postVisitDirectory}
 * method is not invoked.
 */
SKIP_SIBLINGS;
}
```

Also here is a tutorial on [enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).